# Transaction log

Tags: transactions, ms-access-2010

I need to create an update query in Access that will increment by one each transaction by time.

Example: Record 1234 called at 9am, 11am, 6pm on Date Y

I need the output to be:

```
recNum - Date    - Time - Transaction Number
1234 - 11/15/2015 - 9am - 1
1234 - 11/15/2015 - 11am - 2
1234 - 11/15/2015 - 6pm - 3
```

I keep getting hung up on the numbering the transaction properly

Thank you in advance. If I resolve before a reply I will post my solution.

Comment: I got the code right from here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/how-to-generate-sequential-row-numbers-with/8321ed67-70b9-4ffd-b02a-6da2b87c618b?auth=1

SELECT Color, Date,
    (SELECT Count(*)
     FROM table As X
     WHERE X.Color = table.Color
         And X.Date <= table.Date) As SeqNo
FROM table